# How to deselect a selected Form (UITableView) cell - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui

Everything I've found is how we do this in UIKit. Here's a useful extension for no style at all:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func noStyle() {
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

How can I select a cell in a SwiftUI `Form` and remove the selected (namely, still highlighted) cell, even after I push to a new view and return to the view with the selected cell?

To be clear, I am using a `Form` instead of a `List.`

Here's an example:

```
 Form {
    Section(header: Text("Header"))  {
      NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(user: user)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Cell")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
    }
 }
```

Ideally I would be able to do `.selectedStyle(.none)` on the penultimate brace, on the `Section.`

Comment: do you pass `selection: Binding<SelectionValue?>?` to your List ?

Comment: It's not a List. It's a Scroll View with an embedded Form. Sorry. Should have mentioned that. Will update the question.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code example if you want help with your code.

Comment: I've added a direct sample from my app, replacing the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
@State private var selected: User?

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Header"))  {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView(user: user),
                tag: user,
                selection: $selected) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Cell")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                selected = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```